# What is the best way to display a map in RN?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo, mapbox, openstreetmap

I am currently working on a prototype application in native react with EXPO and I need to display a map.

My first idea to make a low cost prototype with respect to the map was to use the OpenStreetMap that I display on my screen.

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSPLR.png)

To do this I use a WebView with the display of an html page with leaflet in it, this is functional but it has a lot of disadvantages especially with regard to the import of local files.

So I looked for another solution, I saw that with OSM, there is not really another solution, so I went to MapBox using the "official" library "@rnmapbox/maps" but it does not work with expo and especially expo go.

Do you have any ideas to use a dynamic map with custom markers etc... in React Native.

I'm thinking of switching to mapbox and not using expo anymore or if you have a better idea I'm interested!

I try WebView with OSM, i see a lot of OSM map library
I try react-native-map and a lot of library

Comment: Have a look to the official expo [`MapView`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/)

Answer (score 1):

you can you react-native-maps in the expo. a map display is free for both application. if you are using react-native-cli the map box is a good choice for free. it has direction, places api and some other that I have used are free.

here is a simple code that you can use.

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
          style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
          zoomLevel={13}
          centerCoordinate={[
            location.coords.longitude,
            location.coords.latitude,
          ]}
          styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Street}
          compassEnabled={false}
          onPress={data =>
            setMarketLocation({
              longitude: data.geometry.coordinates[0],
              latitude: data.geometry.coordinates[1],
            })
          }>
          <MapboxGL.Camera
            zoomLevel={13}
            centerCoordinate={[
              markerLocation.longitude,
              markerLocation.latitude,
            ]}
            animationMode={'flyTo'}
            animationDuration={3000}
          />
          <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
            id={'1212'}
            coordinate={[markerLocation.longitude, markerLocation.latitude]}>
            <View
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              }}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="map-marker"
                size={moderateScale(30)}
                color={'#de0910'}
              />
            </View>
          </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
        </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

another solution is that you can use react-native-maps and use API of mapbox to draw paths , places and other feature that are paid in google-maps. you have to do a litter extra work to map that data for google maps.